# Comparing a particular column in 2 files and return common (UNIX)

Tags: file, unix

I have two files :

File A :

```
apple 123 jfglkfdg
banana 567 kxflkjfkg
orange 431 dkfgd
strawberry 756 kfljxkg
```

File B :

```
banana 8712 sjflgkj
strawberry 812 mdflkgm
```

I just want to compare column 1 of both files and return the common stuff in a third file.

So my output file should look like :

Output File :

```
banana 
strawberry
```

How should I go about ? Is there a one-liner ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 filea|sort>tempfile; cut -d' ' -f1 fileb|sort|join tempfile -; rm tempfile;
```